# FINDSTR Command line (CMD) Output TXT file Turkish character problems

Tags: cmd, command-line, output, findstr

Using the command below, I take the section that says "Name and Surname" and print it to the TXT file, but words containing Turkish letters appear corrupted in the TXT file.

It looks fine on the command screen, but when I print it to the TXT file, Turkish characters do not appear...

I tried many things such as chcp 65001 / 1254, unfortunately it did not fix it,

Command: net user %username% /DOMAIN | FINDSTR /i "Full Name" > userinfo.txt

userinfo.txt Output: Full Name     Ayta‡ G”nc

I request your valuable support,
Kind regards

I tried these but it didn't work :(
chcp 65001
chcp 1254
TXT file save as , UTF8